# Make errors when installing nodejs on OSX 10.7.4

Tags: node.js, osx-lion

When trying to build nodejs, I get `Build failed: -> task failed (err #2): {task: uv uv.h -> uv.a}`

Following these instructions on [github, Building on GNU/Linux and other UNIX][1]

Running:

- OSX v10.7.4
- GCC-10.7.pkg
- XCode 4.3.2 (with `Command-line Tools` installed)

Build output:

```
manzi:node coderama$ git checkout -b v0.8.6
Switched to a new branch 'v0.8.6'
manzi:node coderama$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/coderama/sandbox/installs/node/v0.8.6Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/bin/gcc 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : not found 
Checking for function SSL_library_init   : yes 
Checking for header openssl/crypto.h     : yes 
Checking for library util                : yes 
Checking for library rt                  : not found 
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : no 
'configure' finished successfully (3.653s)
manzi:node coderama$ make
Waf: Entering directory `/Users/coderama/sandbox/node/out'
DEST_OS: darwin
DEST_CPU: x64
Parallel Jobs: 1
Product type: program
[ 1/35] copy: src/node_config.h.in -> out/Release/src/node_config.h
[ 2/35] cc: deps/http_parser/http_parser.c -> out/Release/deps/http_parser/http_parser_3.o
/usr/bin/gcc -rdynamic -pthread -m64 -arch x86_64 -g -O3 -DHAVE_OPENSSL=1 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -DHAVE_FDATASYNC=0 -DARCH="x64" -DPLATFORM="darwin" -D__POSIX__=1 -Wno-unused-parameter -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -IRelease/deps/http_parser -I../deps/http_parser ../deps/http_parser/http_parser.c -c -o Release/deps/http_parser/http_parser_3.o
[ 3/35] src/node_natives.h: src/node.js lib/dgram.js lib/console.js lib/buffer.js lib/querystring.js lib/punycode.js lib/http.js lib/net.js lib/stream.js lib/events.js lib/util.js lib/module.js lib/_debugger.js lib/assert.js lib/fs.js lib/child_process.js lib/os.js lib/readline.js lib/vm.js lib/url.js lib/tls.js lib/crypto.js lib/sys.js lib/https.js lib/freelist.js lib/dns.js lib/_linklist.js lib/buffer_ieee754.js lib/tty.js lib/cluster.js lib/repl.js lib/path.js lib/string_decoder.js lib/timers.js lib/zlib.js lib/constants.js -> out/Release/src/node_natives.h
[ 4/35] uv: deps/uv/include/uv.h -> out/Release/deps/uv/uv.a
rm -f src/ares/*.o
rm -f src/unix/ev/*.o
rm -f src/unix/eio/*.o
rm -f src/unix/*.o
rm -rf test/run-tests.dSYM run-benchmarks.dSYM
rm -f -f src/*.o *.a test/run-tests test/run-benchmarks
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/core.c -o src/unix/core.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/dl.c -o src/unix/dl.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/fs.c -o src/unix/fs.o
src/unix/fs.c: In function ‘uv_fs_fdatasync’:
src/unix/fs.c:459: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fdatasync’
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/cares.c -o src/unix/cares.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/udp.c -o src/unix/udp.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/error.c -o src/unix/error.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/process.c -o src/unix/process.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/tcp.c -o src/unix/tcp.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/pipe.c -o src/unix/pipe.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/tty.c -o src/unix/tty.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/stream.c -o src/unix/stream.o
/usr/bin/gcc --std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Iinclude -Iinclude/uv-private -Isrc/unix/ev -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -Isrc/ares/config_darwin -Isrc  -m64 -arch x86_64 -c src/unix/darwin.c -o src/unix/darwin.o
In file included from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:21:19: error: AE/AE.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:25:35: error: CarbonCore/CarbonCore.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:29:35: error: OSServices/OSServices.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:33:43: error: CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:37:33: error: CFNetwork/CFNetwork.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:41:43: error: LaunchServices/LaunchServices.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:30,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:20:35: error: CoreFoundation/CFBase.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:24:34: error: CoreFoundation/CFURL.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:30,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:51: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:67: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:98: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentCreateWithURL’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:116: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentCopyURL’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:157: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentCreate’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:183: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentGetSchemeName’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:206: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentGetName’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKDocument.h:230: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentGetParent’
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:34,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:20:37: error: CoreFoundation/CFString.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:34,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:54: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKMinTermLength’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:71: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKSubstitutions’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:88: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKStopWords’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:107: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKProximityIndexing’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:127: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKMaximumTerms’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:146: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKTermChars’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:165: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKStartTermChars’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:184: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKEndTermChars’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKAnalysis.h:207: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘kSKLanguageTypes’
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:38,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:28:41: error: CoreFoundation/CFDictionary.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:38,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:75: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:99: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexDocumentIteratorGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:215: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inURL’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:256: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inURL’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:295: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inData’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:332: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inData’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:368: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inData’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:394: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexFlush’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:411: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:430: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetMaximumBytesBeforeFlush’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:456: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexCompact’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:498: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetAnalysisProperties’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:522: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetDocumentCount’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:543: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKDocumentID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:575: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexAddDocumentWithText’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:624: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexAddDocument’

... Similar errors here...
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:888: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexCopyTermIDArrayForDocumentID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:905: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetDocumentTermFrequency’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:928: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetMaximumTermID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:943: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetTermDocumentCount’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:963: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexCopyDocumentIDArrayForTermID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:980: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexCopyTermStringForTermID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKIndex.h:1000: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKIndexGetTermIDForTermString’
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:42,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:32:35: error: CoreFoundation/CFDate.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:42,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:79: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:90: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchOptions’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:131: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFStringRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:132: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKSearchOptions’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:195: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchFindMatches’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:238: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:239: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKDocumentID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:240: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFStringRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:241: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKDocumentID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:272: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:273: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKDocumentID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:274: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKDocumentRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:305: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:306: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKDocumentID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:307: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFURLRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:336: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchGroupGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:359: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchResultsGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:411: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKDocumentRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:411: error: ‘CALLBACK_API_C’ declared as function returning a function
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:435: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inArrayOfInIndexes’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:453: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchGroupCopyIndexes’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:501: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFStringRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:503: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:505: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKSearchResultsFilterCallBack’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:551: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFArrayRef’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:552: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘CFIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:554: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘SKSearchResultsFilterCallBack’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:569: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchResultsGetCount’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:618: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchResultsGetInfoInRange’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSearch.h:650: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSearchResultsCopyMatchingTerms’
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SearchKit.h:46,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:45,
                 from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:69: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryGetTypeID’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:97: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘inString’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:117: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryGetSentenceCount’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:137: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryGetParagraphCount’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:160: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryCopySentenceAtIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:185: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryCopyParagraphAtIndex’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:211: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryCopySentenceSummaryString’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:237: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryCopyParagraphSummaryString’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:278: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryGetSentenceSummaryInfo’
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Headers/SKSummary.h:318: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SKSummaryGetParagraphSummaryInfo’
In file included from src/unix/darwin.c:28:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:48:31: error: Metadata/Metadata.h: No such file or directory
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:49:51: error: DictionaryServices/DictionaryServices.h: No such file or directory
src/unix/darwin.c: In function ‘uv_hrtime’:
src/unix/darwin.c:39: error: ‘Nanoseconds’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/unix/darwin.c:39: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
src/unix/darwin.c:39: error: for each function it appears in.)
src/unix/darwin.c:39: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘enano’
src/unix/darwin.c:41: error: ‘enano’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/unix/darwin.c:41: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘AbsoluteToNanoseconds’
src/unix/darwin.c:41: error: ‘AbsoluteTime’ undeclared (first use in this function)
src/unix/darwin.c:41: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
src/unix/darwin.c:43: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
src/unix/darwin.c: In function ‘uv_exepath’:
src/unix/darwin.c:60: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘malloc’
src/unix/darwin.c:60: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
src/unix/darwin.c:61: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘realpath’
src/unix/darwin.c:61: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
src/unix/darwin.c:64: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘free’
make[1]: *** [src/unix/darwin.o] Error 1
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/coderama/sandbox/node/out'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #2): 
    {task: uv uv.h -> uv.a}
make: *** [program] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by installed XCode's `Command Line Tools`.

This can be done through `Preferences -> Downloads -> Command Line Tools`